# being directed to mysite/install.php after adding database user

Tags: database, wordpress

After not working on my wordpress site for a while I logged on and did some cosmetic work through the dashboard. The next morning I was greeted by an error establishing a connection to the database which showed up on all three of my devices.
Following the advice of a support article from my hosting company I attempted to resolve the problem by creating a new database user and editing the wp-config.php to accept the new user. When I logged on the site again both through the main site and the wp-admin I was directed to mysite/install.php. This happens every time I log on and from any device.
I have spoken to my hosting companies customer service multiple times and tried looking for a solution to the problem and so far have found none. All the site’s files are still there and I can’t seem to find anything wrong. Before this incident, I had made no backup of the site, and as my faith in my host’s automated backup begins to waver I find myself increasingly concerned that I might loose all my work.
Does anyone know of a solution, potential problem I have overlooked or at the very least a way to ensure my site will not be lost?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following steps:

1. Some hosting companies allows to see what is the tables in your database present. Sometimes this tool named "PHPMyAdmin". You should see 10+ tables named like wp_* (wp_user, wp_posts,...).

**If you see that, your data is not lost, so make backup of the database.**

**If you cant see tables, please ask the hosting company to restore backup data, if it exist.**

**If you cannot connect to database using PHPMyAdmin, contact the hosting company.**

Any way, you should get database working from different tool other than Wordpress.

2. Download via FTP the all files of your site.
   At this step backup done.
3. Now you can change the settings of wordpress, and continue work.